# LNPopupController: The popup controller is already in transition. Will ignore this transition request

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, popup, transition

I am using "[LNPopupController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController)" for transitioning the view.

I am stuck in a process which occurs sometimes but yes its an issue for me. I am using **"LNPopupCustomBarViewController"** and presenting a view controller using

```
let popup = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myControllerID") as! MYCONTROLLER
self.navigationController?.popupContentView.popupCloseButtonStyle = .round
self.navigationController?.presentPopupBar(withContentViewController: popup, openPopup: true, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

After presenting and dismissing view controller multiple times simultaneously, I am getting the issue of complete UI distortion. When I debug this issue, I got the output

**LNPopupController: The popup controller is already in transition. Will ignore this transition request.**

It seems that it is due to presenting a view controller when it is still in the transition state. I am clicking the button which is presenting the view controller simultaneously.

How can I stop or restrict user interaction on the view? Or is there any way to check the current transition state of the view?

Answer (score 1):

I think we discussed this in an issue on GitHub, but here is the "official" answer:

You should synchronize your flow. Whenever you call present, dismiss, open and close, there are completion blocks you can provide. In those, you should note the state of the presentation and delay any other calls to those methods until only after the current transition has finished.